# How to change download path in before method with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have the same problem like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032057/how-to-programmatically-set-download-path-in-protractor)

But I would like run each spec next to unique download folder.
Is it possible change download folder in before method on the fly?

Currently, I set folder next way, I would like update default_directory in my tests

```html
capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        loggingPrefs: {
            'browser': 'INFO'
        },
        maxInstances: 2,
        'chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--disable-infobars'],
            prefs: {
                credentials_enable_service: false,
                download: {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'directory_upgrade': true,
                    'default_directory': __dirname.replace('config', 'target\\downloads')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: not exactly, I read this one too.
Goal change default_directory in test

Comment: How can I delete link *This question may already have an answer here:*
It confuses, it is the different topic.